# Ant unless attribute not working?

Tags: java, ant

I must be not understanding the `unless` attribute properly. I have a properties file that has a property as follows:

```
module.project.enabled=false
module.finance.enabled=true
```

And in my Ant build file I have the following piece

```
<echo message="Finance module enabled is ${module.finance.enabled}"/>
<echo message="Project module enabled is ${module.project.enabled}"/>
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="${classes}" debug="true">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="src"/>
        <fileset dir="web/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${GWT.HOME}" includes="gwt-user.jar,gwt-servlet.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    <exclude name="bla/finance/*.java" unless="${module.finance.enabled}"/>
    <exclude name="bla/project/*.java" unless="${module.project.enabled}"/>
</javac>
```

When running my ant target the properties do seem to be read

```
 [echo] Finance module enabled is true
 [echo] Project module enabled is false
```

But when I look at the `${classes}` directory I would have expected to see no classes in the project package and classes in the finance package but alas it seems to be excluding both packages?

Comment: I've only seen `unless` (and `if`) used on tasks, never on nested configuration elements, I don't know if this *should* work.

Comment: are you on 1.8 or older?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Ant 1.7 and prior, the `if` and `unless` attributes only check if a property is set. They don't actually check the value. You could in fact set it to anything, and that'll evaluate as true for `if` and false for `unless`. Likewise if you don't set it at all, you'll get false for `if` and true for `unless`.

In either case I'm not aware of the `if` and `unless` being available for `<exclude>`.

Comment: As of [Ant 1.8.0](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless) a value of true (or on or yes) will enable the item, while false (or off or no) will disable it.

Comment: @JoseK: oh whoa, I didn't even realize that improvement. I updated my answer to reflect that what I said only applies to 1.7 and prior.

Comment: @Clinton: no problem, and good to know it works for `<exclude>` as well. I learned two things from this post :)